# scyllabd ui access for querying data

Tags: scylla

I have scyllaDB installed in cloud. I want to run queries and check the data. Is there any way to access it by any desktop UI client or does by default it provides any web UI to access it

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The typical interface with ScyllaDB is cqlsh which is command line. Documentation is at https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/cqlsh/

There are a few GUIs that claim to be front-ends for Cassandra. These should work for Scylla, but I've never used them.

Comment: I asked around, and got the following suggestions for possible GUIs to Scylla data. 
Cassandra Compatible API: TablePlus, MongoDBManager
DynamoDB Compatible API: Dynobase
Neither I nor my friends who suggested them have tested any of these, so use them at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Professionally I use DataGrip (https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/). But personally I think it is way too expensive, and it's using a lot of RAM, like all Jetbrains Java apps.

I haven't found any open source alternatives that work well, but maybe there is something here: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/drivers.html